# Proof that the condition number of an isometry matrix is 1

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

At first glance it seems somewhat trivial, but I have some doubts, so I'd like your opinion.

We are given that $\left\|Ax\right\| = \left\|x\right\|, ~ \forall x \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$ and want to show that $\text{cond}\left(A\right) = 1$.

As we know, $\text{cond}\left(A\right) = \left\|A\right\| \left\|A^{-1}\right\|$. Moreover, $$\left\|A\right\| = \sup_{\left\|x\right\| = 1} \left\|Ax\right\|$$
so I choose to work in this direction.

Now, the part which I am uncertain about is this:
$$
\left\|Ax\right\| = \left\|x\right\| \Leftrightarrow \left\|A^{-1}Ax\right\| = \left\|A^{-1}x\right\| \Leftrightarrow \left\|x\right\| = \left\|A^{-1}x\right\|
$$

so the matrix $A^{-1}$ is also an isometry.

If the previous holds, it follows trivially that
$$
\left\|A\right\| = \sup_{\left\|x\right\| = 1} \left\|Ax\right\| = \sup_{\left\|x\right\| = 1} \left\|x\right\| = 1
$$

and the same for $A^{-1}$, hence $\text{cond}\left(A\right) = 1$.

Does this seem correct? Can I apply the multiplication with $A^{-1}$ inside the norm? It doesn't seem to contradict my understanding of linear algebra, but then again, I feel a bit rusty...

Comment: You cannot directly apply the multiplication inside the norm unless you know that $A^{-1}$ is an isometry, which is what you need to prove. A better idea is to show that $A^{-1}$ is an isometry, by considering $||A^{-1}y||$ for some $y$. Now notice that $y = Ax$ for some $x$, and $||y|| = ||x||$ by hypothesis.

Comment: If $A$ is an isometry, isn't $A^{-1}$ an isometry as well?

Comment: Since $A$ is invertible (it is trivial to show)  IMHO there is nothing wrong to write: $||Ax||=||x||=||AA^{-1}x||=||A^{-1} x||$ as a proof that $A^{-1}$ is isometric too. I think your proof is correct. Just replace $||A^{-1}A x||$ by $||AA^{-1} x||$

Comment: @AlexanderVigodner: Yes, what you wrote is a correct proof of the fact. However, since the OP asked about "applying the multiplication inside the norm", I believe he is asking whether we can say that $||Ax|| = ||x|| \Rightarrow ||BAx|| = ||Bx||$, which is false.

Comment: @Pedro Mile, yes I thought OP made just a typo but it seems for me you are correct he did what you wrote.

Comment: @Pedro Yes, I did indeed ask about whether it's OK to make this precise multiplication, I had some doubts about it. It's clear that I cannot, and thank you for your kind answers! You helped me out a lot, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is an isometry you have $\|Ax\| = \|x\|$, and so $\|A\|=1$.

If $A$ is an isometry, then so it $A^{-1}$. To see this, note that since
$\|Ax\| = \|x\|$, $A$ is invertible. Letting $x=A^{-1} y$ gives $\|y\| = \| A^{-1} y \|$. Hence $\|A^{-1}\| =1$.

Comment: Basically the comment of @PedroMilet, backed by AlexanderVidognet, but I'm accepting your answer as correct. Thank you again! :)